# Spring boot + Repository + Spark Integration

Tags: apache-spark, spring-data-jpa, notserializableexception

When I try to add Repository support to my Spring boot application with Spark integrated, the application is not starting up and I get the below exception trace.

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:416)
at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:406)

Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1184)

This is thrown on executing the below code:

JavaDStream changePayStream = records.map(new Function<ConsumerRecord<String, String>, String>() {

```
            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public String call(ConsumerRecord<String, String> kafkaRecord) throws Exception {
                return kafkaRecord.offset() + "~>" + kafkaRecord.partition() + "~>" + kafkaRecord.key() + "~>"
                        + kafkaRecord.value();
            }
        });
```

If I remove the spring boot OOTB Repository code, then this exception is not thrown.

**Repository Interface:**
@Repository
public interface XYZRepository extends JpaRepository<XYZRepositoryEntity, Integer> {

```
@Query(value = QueryConstants.QUERY_ABC, nativeQuery = true)
Collection<AsgnCtgySubCtgyRepositoryEntity> findAllXyzNative();
```

}

**Entity Class:**
import java.io.Serializable;

@Entity
public class XYZRepositoryEntity implements Serializable {

```
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
private Integer id;
```

......

Could you please let me know how to solve this?

Thanks,
Venkatesh

I tried to add implements Serializable (both java.io and scala packages) in all the entity classes and other classes applicable.
But this exception is mainly on the OOTB class - org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.